# Change the order of templates in wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, templates

When I go into the Wordpress Editor, the template files are ordered by the file name. For example:

404.php
footer.php
front-page.php
...
..
page.php

I would like to put this list so that it is ordered by the "Template Name" defined inside the template files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no usable hook in theme-editor.php nor in class-wp-theme.php allowing you to sort file list.

WordPress uses custom scandir function to get files and then it simply prints them through foreach loop.

You would have to modify WordPress admin core files in order to change this - and it isn't recomemended.

**EDIT**: There might be an possibility to change this order only with one slight edit inside your WordPress install. You can prepare a plugin which removes default theme editor menu from admin and ads another link to your custom theme-editor.php (located in wp-admin directory) This way:

```
function adjust_the_wp_menu() {
  remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' );
  add_submenu_page('themes.php', _x('Editor', 'theme editor'), _x('Editor', 'theme editor'), 'edit_themes', 'my-theme-editor.php');
}
```

This code presumes you have made a copy of theme-editor.php (named my-theme-editor.php) with exactly the same content as original theme-editor.php. The only chage would be to replace all "theme-editor.php" occurences inside your my-theme-editor.php file to "my-theme-editor.php".

Than you'll always enter this file from admin menu when clicked on Editor. And the whole file is yours and you can try to change order in way you want. Thant you would have to manage to loop your files in right way. It is not so hard, but you pay attantion also to stylesheets being appended to php files...

And as a present, I've prepared my-theme-editor.php file for you ;) Here it is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Theme editor administration panel.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */

/** WordPress Administration Bootstrap */
require_once('./admin.php');

if ( is_multisite() && ! is_network_admin() ) {
    wp_redirect( network_admin_url( 'my-theme-editor.php' ) );
    exit();
}

if ( !current_user_can('edit_themes') )
    wp_die('<p>'.__('You do not have sufficient permissions to edit templates for this site.').'</p>');

$title = __("Edit Themes");
$parent_file = 'themes.php';

get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
'id'        => 'overview',
'title'     => __('Overview'),
'content'   =>
    '<p>' . __('You can use the Theme Editor to edit the individual CSS and PHP files which make up your theme.') . '</p>
    <p>' . __('Begin by choosing a theme to edit from the dropdown menu and clicking Select. A list then appears of all the template files. Clicking once on any file name causes the file to appear in the large Editor box.') . '</p>
    <p>' . __('For PHP files, you can use the Documentation dropdown to select from functions recognized in that file. Lookup takes you to a web page with reference material about that particular function.') . '</p>
    <p id="newcontent-description">' . __('In the editing area the Tab key enters a tab character. To move below this area by pressing Tab, press the Esc key followed by the Tab key.') . '</p>
    <p>' . __('After typing in your edits, click Update File.') . '</p>
    <p>' . __('<strong>Advice:</strong> think very carefully about your site crashing if you are live-editing the theme currently in use.') . '</p>
    <p>' . __('Upgrading to a newer version of the same theme will override changes made here. To avoid this, consider creating a <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes" target="_blank">child theme</a> instead.') . '</p>' .
    ( is_network_admin() ? '<p>' . __('Any edits to files from this screen will be reflected on all sites in the network.') . '</p>' : '' )
) );

get_current_screen()->set_help_sidebar(
    '<p><strong>' . __('For more information:') . '</strong></p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development" target="_blank">Documentation on Theme Development</a>') . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes" target="_blank">Documentation on Using Themes</a>') . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files" target="_blank">Documentation on Editing Files</a>') . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags" target="_blank">Documentation on Template Tags</a>') . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="http://wordpress.org/support/" target="_blank">Support Forums</a>') . '</p>'
);

wp_reset_vars( array( 'action', 'error', 'file', 'theme' ) );

if ( $theme )
    $stylesheet = $theme;
else
    $stylesheet = get_stylesheet();

$theme = wp_get_theme( $stylesheet );

if ( ! $theme->exists() )
    wp_die( __( 'The requested theme does not exist.' ) );

if ( $theme->errors() && 'theme_no_stylesheet' == $theme->errors()->get_error_code() )
    wp_die( __( 'The requested theme does not exist.' ) . ' ' . $theme->errors()->get_error_message() );

$allowed_files = $theme->get_files( 'php', 1 );
//BINDA: Copy allowed files before stylesheets are added to your own varible to be able to sort templates without stylesheets
$myallowed_files = $allowed_files; 
$has_templates = ! empty( $allowed_files );
$style_files = $theme->get_files( 'css' );
$allowed_files['style.css'] = $style_files['style.css'];
$allowed_files += $style_files;

if ( empty( $file ) ) {
    $relative_file = 'style.css';
    $file = $allowed_files['style.css'];
} else {
    $relative_file = stripslashes( $file );
    $file = $theme->get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $relative_file;
}

validate_file_to_edit( $file, $allowed_files );
$scrollto = isset( $_REQUEST['scrollto'] ) ? (int) $_REQUEST['scrollto'] : 0;

switch( $action ) {
case 'update':
    check_admin_referer( 'edit-theme_' . $file . $stylesheet );
    $newcontent = stripslashes( $_POST['newcontent'] );
    $location = 'my-theme-editor.php?file=' . urlencode( $relative_file ) . '&theme=' . urlencode( $stylesheet ) . '&scrollto=' . $scrollto;
    if ( is_writeable( $file ) ) {
        //is_writable() not always reliable, check return value. see comments @ http://uk.php.net/is_writable
        $f = fopen( $file, 'w+' );
        if ( $f !== false ) {
            fwrite( $f, $newcontent );
            fclose( $f );
            $location .= '&updated=true';
            $theme->cache_delete();
        }
    }
    wp_redirect( $location );
    exit;
break;

default:

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );

    update_recently_edited( $file );

    if ( ! is_file( $file ) )
        $error = true;

    $content = '';
    if ( ! $error && filesize( $file ) > 0 ) {
        $f = fopen($file, 'r');
        $content = fread($f, filesize($file));

        if ( '.php' == substr( $file, strrpos( $file, '.' ) ) ) {
            $functions = wp_doc_link_parse( $content );

            $docs_select = '<select name="docs-list" id="docs-list">';
            $docs_select .= '<option value="">' . esc_attr__( 'Function Name...' ) . '</option>';
            foreach ( $functions as $function ) {
                $docs_select .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( urlencode( $function ) ) . '">' . htmlspecialchars( $function ) . '()</option>';
            }
            $docs_select .= '</select>';
        }

        $content = esc_textarea( $content );
    }

    ?>
<?php if ( isset( $_GET['updated'] ) ) : ?>
 <div id="message" class="updated"><p><?php _e( 'File edited successfully.' ) ?></p></div>
<?php endif;

$description = get_file_description( $file );
$file_show = array_search( $file, array_filter( $allowed_files ) );
if ( $description != $file_show )
    $description .= ' <span>(' . $file_show . ')</span>';
?>
<div class="wrap">
<?php screen_icon(); ?>
<h2><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2>

<div class="fileedit-sub">
<div class="alignleft">
<h3><?php echo $theme->display('Name'); if ( $description ) echo ': ' . $description; ?></h3>
</div>
<div class="alignright">
    <form action="my-theme-editor.php" method="post">
        <strong><label for="theme"><?php _e('Select theme to edit:'); ?> </label></strong>
        <select name="theme" id="theme">
<?php
foreach ( wp_get_themes( array( 'errors' => null ) ) as $a_stylesheet => $a_theme ) {
    if ( $a_theme->errors() && 'theme_no_stylesheet' == $a_theme->errors()->get_error_code() )
        continue;

    $selected = $a_stylesheet == $stylesheet ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "\n\t" . '<option value="' . esc_attr( $a_stylesheet ) . '"' . $selected . '>' . $a_theme->display('Name') . '</option>';
}
?>
        </select>
        <?php submit_button( __( 'Select' ), 'button', 'Submit', false ); ?>
    </form>
</div>
<br class="clear" />
</div>
<?php
if ( $theme->errors() )
    echo '<div class="error"><p><strong>' . __( 'This theme is broken.' ) . '</strong> ' . $theme->errors()->get_error_message() . '</p></div>';
?>
    <div id="templateside">
<?php
if ( $allowed_files ) :
    if ( $has_templates || $theme->parent() ) :
?>
    <h3><?php _e('Templates'); ?></h3>
    <?php if ( $theme->parent() ) : ?>
    <p class="howto"><?php printf( __( 'This child theme inherits templates from a parent theme, %s.' ), '<a href="' . self_admin_url('my-theme-editor.php?theme=' . urlencode( $theme->get_template() ) ) . '">' . $theme->parent()->display('Name') . '</a>' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <ul>
<?php
    endif;

//Loop throught myallowed files (copied abowe) and replace cutom page templates key
    foreach ( $myallowed_files as $file => $full_path ) {
        if ( ! preg_match( '|Template Name:(.*)$|mi', file_get_contents( $full_path ), $header ) )
            continue;
        unset( $myallowed_files[ $file ] );
        $myallowed_files[ strtolower(_cleanup_header_comment( $header[1] )) ] = $full_path;
    }
//Sort by key
    ksort( $myallowed_files );
//Add stylesheets
    $style_files = $theme->get_files( 'css' );
    $myallowed_files['style.css'] = $style_files['style.css'];
    $myallowed_files += $style_files;
//Loop myallowed files in desired order
    foreach ( $myallowed_files as $filename => $absolute_filename ) :
        if ( 'style.css' == $filename )
            echo "\t</ul>\n\t<h3>" . _x( 'Styles', 'Theme stylesheets in theme editor' ) . "</h3>\n\t<ul>\n";

        $file_description = get_file_description( $absolute_filename );
        if ( $file_description != basename( $filename ) )
            $file_description .= '<br /><span class="nonessential">(' . $filename . ')</span>';

        if ( $absolute_filename == $file )
            $file_description = '<span class="highlight">' . $file_description . '</span>';
?>
        <li><a href="my-theme-editor.php?file=<?php echo urlencode( $filename ) ?>&amp;theme=<?php echo urlencode( $stylesheet ) ?>"><?php echo $file_description; ?></a></li>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if ( $error ) :
    echo '<div class="error"><p>' . __('Oops, no such file exists! Double check the name and try again, merci.') . '</p></div>';
else : ?>
    <form name="template" id="template" action="my-theme-editor.php" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'edit-theme_' . $file . $stylesheet ); ?>
        <div><textarea cols="70" rows="30" name="newcontent" id="newcontent" aria-describedby="newcontent-description"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
        <input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $relative_file ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="theme" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $theme->get_stylesheet() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="scrollto" id="scrollto" value="<?php echo $scrollto; ?>" />
        </div>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $functions ) ) : ?>
        <div id="documentation" class="hide-if-no-js">
        <label for="docs-list"><?php _e('Documentation:') ?></label>
        <?php echo $docs_select; ?>
        <input type="button" class="button" value=" <?php esc_attr_e( 'Lookup' ); ?> " onclick="if ( '' != jQuery('#docs-list').val() ) { window.open( 'http://api.wordpress.org/core/handbook/1.0/?function=' + escape( jQuery( '#docs-list' ).val() ) + '&amp;locale=<?php echo urlencode( get_locale() ) ?>&amp;version=<?php echo urlencode( $wp_version ) ?>&amp;redirect=true'); }" />
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <div>
        <?php if ( is_child_theme() && $theme->get_stylesheet() == get_template() ) : ?>
            <p><?php if ( is_writeable( $file ) ) { ?><strong><?php _e( 'Caution:' ); ?></strong><?php } ?>
            <?php _e( 'This is a file in your current parent theme.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php
    if ( is_writeable( $file ) ) :
        submit_button( __( 'Update File' ), 'primary', 'submit', true );
    else : ?>
<p><em><?php _e('You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions">the Codex</a> for more information.'); ?></em></p>
<?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
endif; // $error
?>
<br class="clear" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#template').submit(function(){ $('#scrollto').val( $('#newcontent').scrollTop() ); });
    $('#newcontent').scrollTop( $('#scrollto').val() );
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
break;
}

include(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php' );
```

Except replaced string "theme-editor.php" to "my-theme-editor.php" there are changes only at line 62 and than, extended one, on line 180.

But, use it carefully - I have't tested it properly, but it seems working. The punch line is that, when you've got a plugin removing admin menu and replacing it with your own link to my-theme-editor.php, your my-theme-editor.php file won't get replaced by new version of WordPress. And If it gets removed, you can simply copy that back.